# Consumer-producer in wcf

Tags: wcf

Is there any example of a consumer-producer type web service written in WCF? What I am trying to do is write a web service where a producer can publish/upload variables (in this case, cookies), via a Method, and the consumer will recieve each new published cookie (or can be anything).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for callback operations. The consumer can subscribe to receive each generated cookie.

Here is a decent writeup:
http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx